# iOS 5 Music App Grey circle with a square inside it next to the song title - what does it indicate?

Tags: ios, music

I had a few problems downloading a few tracks from the iTunes store direct to my phone. As a result I seem to have placeholder versions of the songs that will let me stream them but not play them.

In the library they have a grey icon next to the song titles a circle with a small square inside, very much like a stop icon but it seems to do nothing.

What is this icon and what does it indicate?

[image]

The screenshot shows the problem tracks with icon and the ones that have synced over from iTunes (which are "normal").

I do use iCloud and have music automatically download, I don't have Match.

The name of the artist and my name being the same is just a co-incidence.

Comment: Screenshot please.

Comment: Hold down the home button and click the lock button to take a screenshot

Comment: You had two separate questions in here initially: what is the icon and what does it mean, and how can I get rid of these duplicates and sync my music. To avoid having multiple questions per post, I've edited out your second question. Please feel free to ask it separately. Please take a look at the [FAQs](http://apple.stackexchange.com/faq) for more info. Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well, that symbol is the download progress indicator. It appears when you buy a song from the iTunes Store directly on your device. The progress is shown in a bar that goes around the circular track on the outside.

It means that it can be listened to via streaming (by clicking on it in the normal manner) if you have a suitable internet connection but has not yet been downloaded to the device.

Comment: I was going to suggest the download was too large for cellular download, but the phone shows wifi so I am stumped. Try entering the iTunes app and checking/cancelling downloads.

Comment: This figures. Eventually I got it to disappear by cancelling and restarting the download and just leaving it until it finally completed (after sitting in waiting for several hours).