# In the iOS 5 Music App, some songs have a circle with small square beside them

Tags: ios, iphone, music

I would like to know how to **remove** the songs with this shape next to their title because they seem to mess up the song play. When they appear the music app stops playing music.

[image]

Comment: possible duplicate of [iOS 5 Music App Grey circle with a square inside it next to the song title - what does it indicate?](http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/44139/ios-5-music-app-grey-circle-with-a-square-inside-it-next-to-the-song-title-wha)

Comment: @patrix: not really a duplicate – that question asks what the symbol means, not how to get rid of it (actually, the “how to get rid of it” was edited out of the question). There is a resolution outlined in the comments, but it is not in the scope of the question, never mind an answer.

Answer (score 1):

i just had the same problem. what i did was i downloaded other songs of the same artist and i deleted the whole music section of the artist. (i hope that makes sense) i have an ipad and it happened to some of my taylor swift songs so i redownloaded all my other taylor swift songs and i went to the artist section in the music library on my ipad and i deleted taylor swift and the songs with the grey circle disappeared. i hope this helped!

Answer (score 0):

This question looks like a duplicate of: [iOS 5 Music App Grey circle with a square inside it next to the song title - what does it indicate?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/44139/ios-5-music-app-grey-circle-with-a-square-inside-it-next-to-the-song-title-wha)

The symbol is the download progress indicator - songs showing that symbol haven't finished downloading. If the download isn't progressing (the circle isn't filling up), try restarting the downloads in the iTunes app.

Comment: Actually it is not! I know what it is but I cannot remove these songs from my iPhone, (they are dublicates of other existing songs) I even tried to resume the download but nothing happened... These duplicates with the circle shape next to the title mess up the song play on my iPhone....

Comment: @Christos Nix is right - that's what the circles are. Your issue with the inability to remove is separate: you should try killing and restarting the Music app or rebooting the phone.

Comment: As noted in the comment to the question, this is not really a duplicate – that question asks what the symbol means, not how to get rid of it (actually, the “how to get rid of it” was edited out of the question). There is a resolution outlined in the comments, but it is not in the scope of the question, never mind an answer.